# Autocorrelation

Tags: autocorrelation

I am having a data set that is collected over a period from 1990 to 2005. In each year there are more than 25000 observations. Observations for a particular year are unique (i.e. Person A who appears in 1999 is not present in any other years). The dependent variable in binary.
I have constructed a logistic regression model on the entire data set (irrespective of time period).
I want to check for auto correlation. When I did a DW test, I got a d-statistic close to 2 but the p-values is <0.05( meaning true auto correlation is not zero)

Can I use the DW test directly on the residuals (aggregated together irrespective of time) or should I use the DW test over each year's residual ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Breusch–Godfrey test, which tests for serial autocorrelation directly on the residuals. It's worth noting that the presence of autocorrelation in a generalised linear model will not add bias to your parameter estimates and will not affect your predictions. In some cases though, significant autocorrelation may affect the standard error of the estimates, and this could be a problem if your goal is to interpret the coefficients instead of just making predictions.

When strong autocorrelation exists then your model's predictive power is bound to get weaker since a significant portion of the response's variability will be stored within the response itself. You can correct this by adding time-related information as dummy variables into your model. The Breusch–Godfrey or Box-Pierce test as well as the Deviance chi-squared test for saturation will be your diagnostic tools for this.